# How to speed up string operations and avoid slow loops

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am writing a code which makes a lot of combinations (Combinations might not be the right word here, sequences of string in the order they are actually present in the string) that already **exist** in a string. The loop starts adding combinations to a `List<string>` but unfortunately, my loop takes a lot of time when dealing with any file over 200 bytes. I want to be able to work with hundreds of MBs here.

Let me explain what I actually want in the simplest of ways.
Lets say I have a string that is "Afnan is awesome" (-> main string), what I would want is a list of string which encompasses different substring sequences of the main string. For example-> A,f,n,a,n, ,i,s, ,a,w,e,s,o,m,e. Now this is just the first iteration of the loop. With each iteration, my substring length increases, yielding these results for the second iteration -> Af,fn,na,n , i,is,s , a,aw,we,es,so,om,me. The third iteration would look like this: Afn,fna,nan,an ,n i, is,is ,s a, aw, awe, wes, eso, som, ome. This will keep going on until my substring length reaches half the length of my main string.

My code is as follows:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText("MyFilePath");
//Creating my dictionary
List<string> dictionary = new List<string>();
int stringLengthIncrementer = 1;
for (int v = 0; v < (data.Length / 2); v++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < data.Length; x++)
    {
        if ((x + stringLengthIncrementer) > data.Length) break; //So index does not go out of bounds

        if (dictionary.Contains(data.Substring(x, stringLengthIncrementer)) == false) //So no repetition takes place
        { 
            dictionary.Add(data.Substring(x, stringLengthIncrementer)); //To add the substring to my List<string> -> dictionary
        }
    }
        stringLengthIncrementer++; //To increase substring length with each iteration
}
```

I use `data.Length / 2` because I only need combinations at most half the length of the entire string. Note that **I search the entire string for combinations, not half of it.**

To further simplify what I am trying to do -> Suppose I have an input string =

> "abcd"

the output would be =

> a, b, c, d, ab, bc, cd, This rest will be cut out as it is longer than half the length of my primary string -> //abc, bcd, abcd

I was hoping if some regex method may help me achieve this. Anything that doesn't consist of loops. Anything that is exponentially faster than this? Some simple code with less complexity which is more efficient?

**Update**
When I used `Hashset` instead of `List<string>` for my dictionary, I did not experience any change of performance and also got an OutOfMemoryException:

[image: OutOfMemoryException]

Comment: for instance, if the input is abc , the output would be like -> a, b, c, ab, bc, abc. @L.B basically different sequences of strings.

Comment: You could use Hashset instead :)

Comment: Can you demonstrate how I can achieve this through your proposed method @sTrenat

Comment: @AsbahQadeer `My output will be as follows` What do you see in that image. Maybe you should post an output which is more understandable

Comment: Just change your collection from list to hashset

Comment: `if ((x + stringLengthIncrementer) > data.Length) break;` : This test is useless, use the condition in the for loop to stop at the good position.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that actually did help me avoid OutOfBounds error

Comment: I understand but remove this line and use the condition in the `for` loop to avoid the OutOfBounds. `maxx = data.Length - stringLengthIncrementer;for (int x = 0; x < maxx; x++)`

Comment: @L.B doing the math, for a string of length = 100, the number of iterations would be 100*50 = 5000, that means 5000 results. This is just a product, nothing exponential here.

Comment: obviously the results should not be stored in memory, but file or database. It is also easy to parallelize - one thread can do the 2 char string, another the 3 char strings, etc..

Comment: @Slai I've used multithreading, but still, performance for big files is near 0

Comment: @AsbahQadeer with your last update: the subset you need is `n*(n+1)/2` (n 
 is the string length). So it is a n**2 algorithm. For a 100 byte string you have 5050 strings close to your comment. But for a 4k string you would get 8M results.  `I want to be able to work with hundreds of MBs here.` that is not possible. (Ex for 1M string => 500G unique strings, besides the memory cost, you should also add the computation time to generate those 500G strings)

Comment: `but unfortunately, my loop takes a lot of time when dealing with any file over 200 bytes` How long is it taking? How long do you want it to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to simplify the code and very easily parallelize it, but it's not going to be orders of magnitude faster, as you would need to run it on files of 100s of MBs (that's very likely impossible).

```
    var data = File.ReadAllText("MyFilePath");
    var result = Enumerable.Range(1, data.Length / 2)
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(len => new HashSet<string>(
            Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length - len + 1) //Adding the +1 here made it work perfectly
                .Select(x => data.Substring(x, len))))
        .SelectMany(t=>t)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried your code but I received different number of results through my code and your code

Comment: From "i am awesome abc is awesome and ab is also awesome" this string, it missed out on [these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJVU1.png) which my code didn't, can you fix it?

Comment: Basically, it doesn't capture the last character or last sequence of every List<string> it makes. It is really fast, works perfectly apart from not getting the last sequence

Comment: Okay I added +1 to  (data.Length - len) and it worked perfectly

Comment: `AsParallel` does in fact make it faster

Comment: It may for some inputs - but it certainly doesn't for **all** inputs @AsbahQadeer . If `data` is, for example, "abasdjasdsgjashdjhahgsxnxakjshdkjashddnxn asdhhaskjdhx kajkshdhdkjashdk" then adding `.AsParallel()` makes it take 3+ times as long (vs just removing `AsParallel()`.

Comment: Yes, the overhead of AsParallel may make it slower in some cases. I'd venture to guess that with larger datasets, it will usually prevail. You could also try a custom partitioner: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl

Answer (score 0):

General improvements, that you can do in your code to improve the performance (I don't consider if there're other more optimal solutions).

1. calculate data.Substring(x, stringLengthIncrementer) only once
2. as you do search, use `SortedList`, it will be faster.
3. initialize the `List` (or `SortedList`, or whatever) with calculated number of items. Like new List(CalucatedCapacity).

or you can try to write an algorithm that produces combinations without checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `HashSet` combined with `MoreLINQ`'s `Batch` feature (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)) to simplify the code a little.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string data = File.ReadAllText("MyFilePath");
    //string data = "Afnan is awesome";

    var dictionary = new HashSet<string>();
    for (var stringLengthIncrementer = 1; stringLengthIncrementer <= (data.Length / 2); stringLengthIncrementer++)
    {
        foreach (var skipper in Enumerable.Range(0, stringLengthIncrementer))
        {
            var batched = data.Skip(skipper).Batch(stringLengthIncrementer);

            foreach (var batch in batched)
            {
                dictionary.Add(new string(batch.ToArray()));
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(dictionary);

    dictionary.ForEach(z => Console.WriteLine(z));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

For this input:

```
"Afnan is awesome askdjkhaksjhd askjdhaksjsdhkajd asjsdhkajshdkjahsd asksdhkajshdkjashd aksjdhkajsshd98987ad asdhkajsshd98xcx98asdjaksjsd askjdakjshcc98z98asdsad"
```

performance is roughly 10x faster than your current code.